# MySQL not returning values from NOT IN function

Tags: mysql, notin

I currently am trying to write a query that shows customers with at least 5 orders and customer with no orders. Orders are tracked in their own table and in order to find customers with 0 orders we have to find the customers NOT IN orders. Below is my query I'm trying to use and it returns the same customer 5 times for zero orders.

```
with t1 as
 (select o.customerNumber, c.customerName, count(o.orderNumber) as FiveOrders
 from orders o join customers c on (o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber)
 group by o.customerNumber having count(o.orderNumber) = 5),
 t2 as
 (select distinct o.customerNumber, c.customerName, count(o.orderNumber) as NoOrders
 from orders o join customers c on (o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber)
 group by c.customerNumber not in(select customerNumber from orders))
 select distinct t1.customerNumber as FiveOrderNumber, t1.customerName as FiveOrderName,
 t2.customerNumber as NoOrderNumber, t2.customerName as NoOrderName
 from t1 join t2
 order by NoOrderName;
```

Any and all help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: You want to get all customers with 5 or 0 orders in one query? How do you excepect the results and what shown when execute the queries.

Comment: I'm looking for customerName and customerNumber for customers with 5 and 0 orders. t1 currently handles finding those with 5 orders and t2 works on finding those with 0. t1 works correctly, but t2 only gets one customer returned when I know theres more.

Comment: You can get customers with 0 orders easily without using count(o.orderNumber), because you want customers who didn't have any order, why count the orders?

Comment: You're right I don't need that included anywhere, but as I'm debugging that value helps me see how many customers each subquery is catching. Either way could you explain how to get customers with 0 orders? I thought my not in function was correct, but it is not working. I also have tried changing the "group by" in t2 into a where but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I just posted my answer, you can try it and then inform us about results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the errors were only in the second table to, I think it is after using
***having*** with condition ***NOT IN*** without any logical comparison, I think you can get wanted results easily like:

```
select distinct customerNumber, customerName, "0" as NoOrders 
from customers 
where customerNumber not in (Select customerNumber from orders)
```

If the ***group by*** is important, you can use it like in your code.

Comment: can you show us table data or just sample of them. try execute the query in the answer speratly

Answer (score 2):

`Zero` or `five` could be counted together with `LEFT JOIN`

```
select c.customerNumber, max(c.customerName) customerName, count(o.orderNumber) as FiveOrdersOrZero
from customers c
left join orders o on o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
group by c.customerNumber 
having count(o.orderNumber) in ( 0, 5 )
order by FiveOrdersOrZero
```